# How to connect a Powershell Azure Function to DocumentDB / CosmosDB

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I wired up an Http Trigger C# function to my DocumentDB data. There I added a `IEnumerable<dynamic> docDBData` as a parameter on the Run method.

How do/can I pass that to a PowerShell Trigger function?

Couldn't find a an example in azure-webjobs-sdk-script repo. Not sure if I'm searching for the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no examples for DocumentDB/CosmosDB and powershell - however, it should be relatively straightforward. The results of your query will be stored in the file `$docDBData` (assuming you named the binding `docDBData`) in json format, just like other trigger/input parameters.

```
$in = Get-Content $triggerInput | ConvertFrom-Json;
$docDBResults = Get-Content $docDBData | ConvertFrom-Json;
...
```

Here's a good resource on the DocumentDB binding in general:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb